# Google OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch when your url contains "&"

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, hybridauth

I am using the PHP HybridAuth library and integrating oauth2 support, all providers such as Yahoo, MSN and Facebook works, except Google, showing

```
The redirect URI in the request: 
https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback&amp;hauth.done=Google did not match a registered redirect URI.
```

My redirect url is : https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback&hauth.done=Google, I've added both urls to see if I can workaround for their non sense escape limitation, e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback&hauth.done=Google
https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback&amp;hauth.done=Google
```

Still no luck...Any idea?

Comment: Try adding the page?  https://www.example.com/auth/index.php?action=callback&hauth.done=Google

Comment: Is it because of & sign or beacuse you are using https page without trsuted certifcate. Check some other URL with trusted certificate

Answer (score 1):

just an assumption, try `urlencode()`'ing the url,

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback" . urlencode("&hauth.done=Google");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use the PHP urlencode function.

```
urlencode — URL-encodes string
(PHP 4, PHP 5)

string urlencode ( string $str )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Example:

```
$encoded_url = urlencode("https://www.example.com/auth?action=callback&hauth.done=Google");
```

More informations:

> **HTML URL Encoding Reference**
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
>
> **PHP urlencode**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php